# Getting average of object within an array

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get an average of the 'min' column within this dataset:

```
var data = [{
    name: "Site A",
    max: 202,
    min: 0,
    var: 202,
    x: 1,
    product: "Diesel",
    case: "Base Case"
  },
  {
    name: "Site B",
    max: 145,
    min: 147,
    var: -2,
    x: 0,
    product: "Diesel",
    case: "Base Case"
  },
  {
    name: "Site C",
    max: 221,
    min: 238,
    var: -17,
    x: 0,
    product: "Diesel",
    case: "Base Case"
  }]
```

Can you please advise how I can do this?>

Comment: There is a `d3.mean()` function that should give you what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`d3.mean()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#mean) which takes an accessor function as the second argument. That accessor function will be presented each object in your array and is used to extract the `.min` property from it.

```
const average = d3.mean(data, d => d.min);
```

Have a look at this working demo:

```js
var data = [{
    name: "Site A",
    max: 202,
    min: 0,
    var: 202,
    x: 1,
    product: "Diesel",
    case: "Base Case"
  },
  {
    name: "Site B",
    max: 145,
    min: 147,
    var: -2,
    x: 0,
    product: "Diesel",
    case: "Base Case"
  },
  {
    name: "Site C",
    max: 221,
    min: 238,
    var: -17,
    x: 0,
    product: "Diesel",
    case: "Base Case"
  }];
  
const average = d3.mean(data, d => d.min);

console.log(average);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```